# Java - Managing multiple asynchronous servlet requests and placing them in a queue to perform tasks

Tags: java, servlets, design-patterns, concurrency

I'm using a Bootstrap Krajee FileInput widget on a webpage.  Hundreds of photos are uploaded to the server through this widget and they are all sent individually as a set of asynchronous calls.  The issue is that our server is having difficulty handling hundreds of photos at once.  It isn't a network issue.  I'm leaning more toward it being a file IO/database performance issue.

I need a way to put these photos all into one queue on the server side and then pop them off, do the work, and send a JSON response back with the servlet.

Can anyone point me to a pattern (or implementation of a pattern that would work well here?  Am I completely off base?

I included a quick drawing illustrating what I think should happen.

[drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDKp9.png)

Comment: you can of course use a messaging queue between your controller and db but before doing that maybe you should first analyze real reason of performance issue. Otherwise even with your new implementation you could still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can fit apache kafka in - between 
http://kafka.apache.org/